# if title contains string 'aaa','bbb' or ,'ccc' replace field {category[1}

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Hello gods of Stackoverflow,

Now i hate to be "that guy" who didnt search properly but i am running into a problem that i need a fix for and can't find a solution i can work with because of my lack in coding skills, my knowledge barely tickles the surface.

Here's the thing.

I am using a tool to import feeds into my website (WP all Import) as woocommerceproducts. But in the categorization the feed suppliers made errors which i want to tackle without emailing them everytime i stumble upon one.

i.e: the title contains words like satchel, bag, clutch etc but the product is categorized as 'jewellery > earrings' in the CSV or XML.

The import tool will ask me where to find the product category, i point it to the node {category[1]}

But when the category is missing or faulty i want it to check the title for certain words, and if present change the value of it to that found word.

```
something like: 

[if ({title[1]}contains "satchel") {
    category = "bags > satchel",
} else if ({title[1]} contains clutch) {
    category = "bags > clutch",
} else {
    category = {sub_category[1]} #the normal value if nothing was found 
}]
```

I just can't find the pieces to put the formatting together. I might need to work towards a function that i could expand to generate categories based solely out of presence of certain words in the title but maybe when i get better that would be an option.

I hope i was able to provide a clear view on the problem. The "[    ]" is there because thats how the plugin wants code to be entered instead of a {fieldname[1]}, another example below:

The following was an example of a problem i was able to fix:
i needed to replace values like "0/3months/1/2months" to "0-3 months/1-2months" before i replaced the slash"/" with a pipe"|" for wordpress to recognize it as a seperate value.

```
[str_replace("/","|",
   str_replace("0/3","0-3",
     str_replace("1/2","1-2",
       str_replace("3/6","3-6",{size[1]}))))]
```

The fields can also be used to call functions but only in the 'pro' version of the plugin.

Any help is very much appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [strpos](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php).

Example:

```
if (strpos($title, "satchel") !== false) {
    $category = "bags > satchel";
}
```

Comment: So i could write something like: 

if (strpos({title[1]},"satchel") !== false) {
    $category = "bags > satchel",
} else if (strpos{title[1]}, "clutch") {
    $category = "bags > clutch",
} else {
    $category = {category[1]} 
}

im sorry i dont know how to edit it as a "code"

Comment: Yes, that is the idea

Comment: i tried the code exactly like this:
    '[          if (strpos({title[1]},"Satchel") !== false) { 
 $category = "Tassen>Satchel", 
 } else if (strpos{title[1]},"Travel" !== false) { 
 $category = "Tassen>Travel",
    } else if (strpos{title[1]},"Gusset" !== false) { 
 $category = "Tassen>Gusset", 
 } else { $category = {category_path[1]} 
 }
]
'
But it returned the error: unexpected symbol '!'

i'm sure it's something in the formatting and i've been fiddling around some more but i can't seem to get it right.. any clarification would be welcome and appreciated.

Comment: I just realized, the plugin may not allow php within the brackets: `[...]`, not entirely sure if this would work any way. In my experience it is always easier to ask for a clean and valid source data rather than trying to fix bad data.

Comment: it does allow code inside [...] like i mentioned in the post above. it works perfectly with the str_replace code. i think i need to maybe use a different comparison like == or ===, maybe my if statement can't handle multiple instances of !== ?
I need it as a code because i rely on automated feeds from over 100 sources in the future, importing thousands of products. once i get the correcting code right for a particular advertiser i can forget about it because it will be pretty much self repairing.

Comment: Alright, I will spin up a demo and try some things.

Comment: that would be awesome, i repaired it because i wasnt using ')' where i should be but the unexpected '!' keeps coming up, i also replaced comma's with semicolons. and changed else if to elsif ^^  

  `[if (strpos({title[1]},"Satchel") !== false) { 
 $category = "Tassen>Satchel"; 
 } elseif (strpos({title[1]},"Travel") !== false) { 
 $category = "Tassen>Travel";
    } elseif (strpos({title[1]},"Gusset") !== false) { 
 $category = "Tassen>Gusset"; 
 } else { $category = {category_path[1]} 
 }]`

Answer (score 2):

So after an afternoon of poking around, testing stuff, and not knowing alot about php i came up with a solution with help from a friend.

Wp All Import does **not allow custom php directly from the field itself**, it does however support custom php functions and provides an editor for these on the bottom of the import configuration page. I did the following:

```
<?php


    //Checks Title for keywords and 
    //uses those to create categories
    //We are using our own Main categories so only 
    //sub and subsub categroies need to be created.
    //Call function
    [get_subcat_from_title({title[1]},{category[1]})]
    //Function
    function get_subcat_from_title($title,$defaultcat)
    {    
        if (strpos($title,"Satchel") !== false) {   
            $cat = "Tassen";    
        } elseif (strpos($title,"Travel") !== false) {      
            $cat = "Tassen";     
        } elseif (strpos($title,"Gusset") !== false) {      
            $cat = "Tassen";        
        } else { 
            $cat = $defaultcat;
        }
        return $cat;
    }


    //Checks Title for keywords and uses those to create subcategories
    //Call Function
    [get_subsubcat_from_title({title[1]},{sub_category[1]})]
    //Function
    function get_subsubcat_from_title($title,$defaultcat)
    {    
        if (strpos($title,"Satchel") !== false) {   
            $cat = "Satchel";   
        } elseif (strpos($title,"Travel") !== false) {      
            $cat = "Travel";     
        } elseif (strpos($title,"Gusset") !== false) {      
            $cat = "Gusset";        
        } else { 
            $cat = $defaultcat;
        }
        return $cat;
    }

?>
```

On the Taxonomies, Tags, Categories option we can create our own hierarchical order like this:

```
[main category]
+[sub category]
++[sub sub category]
```

The main category field is given a name we use as our main category.
The sub category is filled with function SUBCAT
The subsub category is filled with function SUBSUBCAT

this way it will create a **parent by our own name**, a **child** that has the named '**Tassen**' if any **keyword** is present, and a **grandchild** with the **specific keyword** as it's name.

This way i can expand the function using all kinds of statements when the right category isn't present in de provided feed.

thanks @sebastianForsberg for responding.

I hope this helps anyone who comes across a similar problem in the future..

Comment: i can chose my answer tomorrow it says. He was very helpful and able to keep me on the strpos path :). Thanks for the input.